# Handling competing requests for the same "id" in different Kubernetes PODs

Tags: concurrency, distributed-system, kubernetes

I have the following problem, I am implementing a delivery management service and a single order can be competed between N deliveryboys, this service is being executed on Kubernetes with 5 PODs of this application.

When a deliveryboy clicks on the APP to accept the order for delivery, this flow must be synchronous to return to the deliveryboy that he was associated with the order.

The problem is that, as the order is competed between N deliveryboys, the N deliveryboys can click on the app to accept the order, so while one request is being processed, the others must remain waiting until the first execution of accepting the order that was initiated for one of the N deliveryboys, has been completed.

My first attempt to deal with this problem was to use RedLock from Redis, but over time it proved problematic as a HUGE number of temporary keys were being created in Redis, referring to the lock, because I needed to lock both the deliveryboy and order and the consumption of CPU and memory resources became very large.

Another alternative I thought of was to use the actor model.

My question is, what would be a good alternative to deal with this type of problem?

Comment: Have you considered a simple SQL database? If that wouldn't work for you it's probably because you didn't state all the problem requirements and constraints.

Comment: How about sharing the order as a message to a Kafka broker and then having all of your delivery boys app consume the message from the broker. You can have a hash of order ID to deny multiple consumption of the same order by different consumers.

Comment: Also how is this related to K8s?